# excel return formula with relative cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets in my excel, the first sheet allows me to select a calculation method from a drop down list and input the variable for the calculation (shown in green cell, the column in blue shows some constant number). The result entry will search for the corresponding calculation formula from my second worksheet (database), then paste the formula to the sheet 1, I need the formula to calculate using the cells in sheet 1 instead of cells in my database.

[image]
[image]

currently I created an user defined function called Eval as below:

```
Function Eval(ref As String)
  Eval = Application.Evaluate(ref)
End Function
```

by combining the Eval with vlookup `:=Eval(VLOOKUP(A3,Database!A2:E10,5,FALSE))` I will get the result that the calculation equation uses the cells from my database, how can I achieve the result which the formula takes cells in sheet 1 during calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to use all formulas within one `CHOOSE` like this:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(A2,"Calculation "&ROW($1:$9),0)),B2*C2*D2,B2*C2-D2,B2+C2-D2,B2^2-C2+D2,B2*D2-C2^2,B2+C2*D2,B2*C2-C2*D2,B2-D2-C2*D2,C2-D2*B2),"")
```

---

Another would be to use the Application.Caller like:

```
Public Function eval(ref As String)
  eval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(ref)
End Function
```

This ensures the use of of the parent of the caller (the sheet with the `eval()` formula) to be used as main-ref.

**EDIT**
Keep in mind that your "rows" are static in the formulas. Going for "Calculation 4" will use row 5 (and not the row of your formula from the first sheet). For this you could use something like:

```
=Eval(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A3,Database!A2:E10,5,FALSE),"##",ROW()))
```

While all row-numbers should be changed to `##` (or whatever unique identifier you like). Then "Calculation 1" would look like: `=B##*C##*D##`

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you very much, the question I posted is only an simplified version. I may have more than 50 equations to consider so in that case the choose formula will be so long. However in your second case, for some reason if I copy your UDF directly to my module, it will work the same as my previous Eval function. Can you please provide me some extra help on that UDF?

Comment: @LiuRoye the `Evaluate` function is executed from a sheet and not from the application. If used like `Sheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(...)` then it will always use "Sheet1". If directly used as `Application.Evaluate(...)`, then it will use the `ActiveSheet`. If used cross several sheets, the `Application.Evaluate(...)` may fail extremely. Do in Sheet2 A1 `A2` and in A2 2. In Sheet1 A2 put `1`. Now using `Sheet2!A1` at Sheet1 and it will show `1`. But If you go to sheet2 and re-enter the `A1` and then go back to sheet1, your formula will show `2` (my code should still show 1)

Comment: @LiuRoye the best way to avoid all that problems, is using full-references like `Sheet1!B2*Sheet1!C2*Sheet1!D2`. This way it should do the way you want it, no matter what ;)